# MarkLogic transform search result option metadata-snippet

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I am using transform results and apply metadata-snippet to extract a property of documents when doing a search. I am not getting the properties and also if I remove the `<preferred-matches>`, the documentation says it needs to return prop-lastmodifed. But I am not getting any. Following is what I am doing

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
declare namespace html = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";
declare namespace prop = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/property";
declare namespace meta = "http://ir.abbivenet.com/content-repo/metadata";
import module namespace search = "http://marklogic.com/appservices/search" at "/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search.xqy";

let $q := "(TNF)"

let $options := 
  <options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
    <term>
      <term-option>case-insensitive</term-option>
      <term-option>punctuation-insensitive</term-option>
      <term-option>whitespace-insensitive</term-option>
      <term-option>wildcarded</term-option>
    </term>
    <transform-results apply="metadata-snippet">
       <preferred-matches>
        <element ns="http://ir.abbivenet.com/content-repo/metadata" name="id"/>
      </preferred-matches>
    </transform-results>
    <!--
    <return-facets>false</return-facets>
    <return-values>false</return-values>
    <return-constraints>false</return-constraints>
    <return-frequencies>false</return-frequencies>
    <return-qtext>false</return-qtext>
    <search-option>unfaceted</search-option>
    <search-option>score-simple</search-option>
    -->
  </options>

let $start := 1
let $page-length :=1000000

let $query-original := cts:query(search:parse($q, $options))


let $result := search:resolve(document { $query-original }/*,
                              $options,
                              $start,
                              $page-length)

return $result
```

Following is the snippet of my results

```
<search:response snippet-format="metadata-snippet" total="546" start="1" page-length="1000000" xmlns:search="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
  <search:result index="1" 
                 uri="/documents/BioEln/79ca10522ef2bd3da946623c8dd1f5c6c786d983.xml/extractedText/79ca10522ef2bd3da946623c8dd1f5c6c786d983.xhtml" 
                 path="fn:doc("/documents/BioEln/79ca10522ef2bd3da946623c8dd1f5c6c786d983.xml/extractedText/79ca10522ef2bd3da946623c8dd1f5c6c786d983.xhtml")" 
                 score="246272" confidence="0.7858079" fitness="1">
    <search:snippet>
      <search:match 
         path="fn:doc("/documents/BioEln/79ca10522ef2bd3da946623c8dd1f5c6c786d983.xml/extractedText/79ca10522ef2bd3da946623c8dd1f5c6c786d983.xhtml")">
      </search:match>
    </search:snippet>
  </search:result>
  <search:result index="2" 
                 uri="/documents/BioEln/568819dbbf44a75598739e8272d0de5956dadff4.xml/extractedText/568819dbbf44a75598739e8272d0de5956dadff4.xhtml"
                 path="fn:doc("/documents/BioEln/568819dbbf44a75598739e8272d0de5956dadff4.xml/extractedText/568819dbbf44a75598739e8272d0de5956dadff4.xhtml")" 
                 score="246272" confidence="0.7858079" fitness="1">
  <search:snippet>
    <search:match path="fn:doc("/documents/BioEln/568819dbbf44a75598739e8272d0de5956dadff4.xml/extractedText/568819dbbf44a75598739e8272d0de5956dadff4.xhtml")">
    </search:match>
  </search:snippet>
</search:result>
<search:result index="3" uri="
```

Answer (score 3):

To quote the [search-dev guide](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/query-options#id_36346):

> The apply="metadata-snippet" option returns the specified preferred elements from the properties documents. If no  element is specified, then the metadata-snippet option returns the prop:last-modified element for its snippet, and if the prop:last-modified element does not exist, it returns an empty snippet.

Since MarkLogic 6 or 7, last-modified property is not provided out of the box any more. That saves on properties fragments you often don't need. You can enable it via the Admin UI. Enable the `maintain last modified` setting of your content database. I am guessing you haven't done that in your database, which is why you are getting the empty snippet as result.

HTH!

Comment: I do have `<id>` as the properties for all my documents and when I tell to return `<id>` as in the code above.. I get empty snippets

Comment: Are you sure that id element is in the correct namespace?

Comment: yes.. and when I write my custom trasform function it works

Comment: Can you share your custom transform in a gist?

Comment: `declare function repo-lib:snippet($doc as node(), $query as schema-element(cts:query),$options as element(search:transform-results)?) as element(search:snippet)
{
(: Do whatever you like with each match. :)
    element search:snippet {xdmp:document-properties(xdmp:node-uri($doc)) }
};`

Comment: Have you considered using a custom `result-decorator` instead?